# Unable to get data from TextBox/DDL in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have been looking all over web and testing what I think would work. I feel close but I guess not close enough. I need help pull the data in. The button click is to submit/insert data into the DB which I have not completed that part. Right now I am working on just getting data from the Gridview and need help.

The Update Button is outside the Gridview. I want end user to complete GridView then click update to submit data from Gridview to database.

Here is ASPX

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="dsSnumbers" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"
                                GridLines="Horizontal" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" 
                                BorderWidth="3px">
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SerialNumber">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" BackColor="BurlyWood" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SerialNumber") %>' ></asp:TextBox>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DdStatus" runat="server" DataSourceID="Ds_Variables" DataTextField="Status" DataValueField="Value" Height="16px"></asp:DropDownList>

                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dept">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DdDept" runat="server" DataSourceID="Ds_Variables" DataTextField="Status" DataValueField="Value" Height="16px"></asp:DropDownList>

                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Update">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" RepeatLayout="Flow" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                                                runat="server">
                                                <asp:ListItem Text="Modify?" Value="1">
                                                </asp:ListItem>
                                            </asp:CheckBoxList>
                                            <br />
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                                <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#339966" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#487575" />
                                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
                                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#275353" />
                               <%-- <EmptyDataTemplate></EmptyDataTemplate>--%>
                            </asp:GridView>
```

And here is the .CS side

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    foreach (GridViewRow g1 in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        int RI = g1.RowIndex;
        //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        TextBox test = (TextBox)g1.Cells[0].FindControl("TextBox1");
        TextBox test1 = (TextBox)g1.Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");


        GridViewRow Grow = (GridViewRow)g1.NamingContainer;
        TextBox txtledName = (TextBox)Grow.FindControl("TextBox1");

        DropDownList testdd1 = (DropDownList)g1.Cells[0].FindControl("DdStatus");
        DropDownList testdd2 = (DropDownList)g1.Cells[1].FindControl("DdStatus");

        string test1324 = g1.Cells[1].Text;
        string test2 = g1.Cells[2].Text;
        string test3 = g1.Cells[3].Text;

    }

}
```

**Update:**

When I run the below I can read the button click whether it is checked or not. However the textbox and dropdown still do nothing. I show ONLY rindex is pulling values. None of the others.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        int rindex = row.DataItemIndex;
        //string Test = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[0].Controls[0])).Text;
        TextBox IDNum = (TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox1");
        string textBox1 = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;

        string ddl1 = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("DdStatus")).SelectedValue;
        string ddl2 = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("DdDept")).SelectedValue;

        int ddl1231 = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("DdStatus")).SelectedIndex;
        int ddl1232 = ((DropDownList)row.FindControl("DdDept")).SelectedIndex;
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Keeps pulling in NULL values from textbox and Dropdownlist

Comment: Try `string textBox1 = ((TextBox)g1.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text;` But I'd suggest you drop a breakpoint in there and shift-F9 on `g1` to see what's happening in there. Your issue could be due to PostBack.